# Filtering on a condition using the column names and not numbers

Tags: linux, awk, terminal, grep, bioinformatics

I am trying to filter a text file with columns based on two conditions. Due to the size of the file, I cannot use the column numbers (as there are thousands and are unnumbered) but need to use the column names. I have searched and tried to come up with multiple ways to do this but nothing is returned to the command line.

Here are a few things I have tried:

`awk '($colname1==2 && $colname2==1) { count++ } END { print count }' file.txt` 
to filter out the columns based on their conditions

and
 `head -1 file.txt | tr '\t' | cat -n | grep "COLNAME`
to try and return the possible column number related to the column.

An example file would be:

```
ID  ad   bd

1   a   fire
2   b   air
3   c   water
4   c   water
5   d   water
6   c   earth
```

Output would be:
2 (count of ad=c and bd=water)

Comment: What does the size of the file have to do with anything?

Comment: consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, provide sample input and the (correct) desired output

Comment: Are your columns separated by tabs or blanks or any white space are they fixed-width fields or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your input file and the implied conditions this should work

```
$ awk -v c1='ad' -v c2='bd' 'NR==1{n=split($0,h); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) col[h[i]]=i} 
                             $col[c1]=="c" && $col[c2]=="water"{count++} END{print count+0}' file

2
```

or you can replace c1 and c2 with the values in the script as well.

to find the column indices you can run

```
$ awk -v cols='ad bd' 'BEGIN{n=split(cols,c); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) colmap[c[i]]} 
                       NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i in colmap) print $i,i; exit}' file

ad 2
bd 3
```

or perhaps with this chain

```
$ sed 1q file | tr -s ' ' \\n | nl | grep -E 'ad|bd'

     2  ad
     3  bd
```

although may have false positives due to regex match...

You can rewrite the `awk` to be more succinct

```
$ awk -v cols='ad bd' '{while(++i<=NF) if(FS cols FS ~ FS $i FS) print $i,i; 
                        exit}' file

ad 2
bd 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run the script and change the variables I am at least getting a return, but its zero

Comment: Did you try with the sample input you posted? It should be easy to validate the script that way.

Comment: I did, it works on the example file but not on the actual file. I would give the data but it is quite huge and sensitive information. Is there any way I could write a script that would return the column number for the variable given? I tried to do that in the above question but didnt have success

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in an earlier comment, the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359699/133219 shows how to do this:

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[$i] = i
        }
    }
    ($(f["ad"]) == "c") && ($(f["bd"]) == "water") { cnt++ }
    END { print cnt+0 }
' file
2
```

I'm assuming your input is tab-separated due to the `tr '\t'` in the command in your question that looks like you're trying to convert tabs to newlines to convert column names to numbers. If I'm wrong and they're just separated by any chains of white space then remove `-F'\t'` from the above.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`miller`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/10min.html) toolkit to manipulate tab-delimited files using column names. Below is a one-liner that filters a tab-delimited file (delimiter is specified using `--tsv`) and writes the results to STDOUT together with the header. The header is removed using `tail` and the lines are counted with `wc`.

```
mlr --tsv filter '$ad == "c" && $bd == "water"' file.txt | tail -n +2 | wc -l
```

Prints:

```
2
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[`miller` manual](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manpage.html)

Note that [`miller`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) can be easily installed, for example, using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html), like so:

```
conda create --name miller miller
```

Answer (score 0):

For years it bugged me there is no succinct way in Unix to do this sort of thing, although [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is a pretty good tool for this. Recently I wrote [`pick`](https://github.com/micans/bash-utils) to choose columns by name, and additionally modify, combine and add them by name, as well as filtering rows by clauses using column names. The solution to the above with `pick` is

```
pick -h @ad=c @bd=water < data.txt | wc -l
```

By default pick prints the header of the selected columns, `-h` is to omit it. To print columns you simply name them on the command line, e.g.

```
pick ad water < data.txt | wc -l
```

Pick has many modes, all of them focused on manipulating columns and selecting/filtering rows with a minimal amount of syntax.